# Using Id and itemId in Extjs to access components

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

In ExtJs Best practices I gone through not to use Id for accessing Ext Components rather use ItemId, I am very new in accessing components using `ItemID`, does any one can help me in default syntax or the way to access components.

Also on click of yes in a message box I need to disable some components in masked page, whether this can be achieved with the help of `ItemID`? Please explain.

I feel when using `ItemiD` it may return array of elements/components, so if need to get an exact component I need to iterate again. I have this ques too....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basic difference between id and itemId is

When you use an id for a component, **there must be a single instance of this component**, **If you create another instance that has the same id**, you will have problems as the DOM is confused.

when you use itemId, it should be unique only within the component's immediate container.the component's container maintains a list of children ids.

so the best practice is to use itemId instead of id

now How to access?

if you use id

`Ext.getCmp('id')`

or

`document.getElementById('id')`

or

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#id")[0]`

if you use itemId

`parentContainer.getComponent('child_itemId')`,

refer following example

e.g

```
 var parentContainer= Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
         initComponent: function(){
            Ext.applyIf(me, {
               //childrens
               items: [{
                          xtype:'textfield',
                          itemId:'text'
                       },
                       {
                           xtype:'panel',
                           itemId:'childpanel',
                           items:[
                                 {
                                     xtype:'combobox',
                                     itemId:'combo'
                                 }
                           ]
                       }]
            });
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },
        renderTo:Ext.getBody()

    })
```

in above example

for accessing  textfield use

```
parentContainer.getComponent('text');
```

for accessing combobox use

```
parentContainer.getComponent('childpanel').getComponent('combo');
```

or

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#combo")[0];
```

this will return array of item with id combo in page
for these you should use unique itemId so you will get the first item you are searching for

or

```
parentContainer.queryById('combo');
```

you can also use `Ext.util.MixedCollection`

```
        var fields = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
        fields.addAll(parentContianer.query('[isFormField]'));
        var Combo = fields.get('combo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you define Panel like below which have a button. Now to access this button you can use Extjs ComponentQuery api. To uniquely identify my button I can use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('myPanel button[itemId=myButton]')[0]. For more details check http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

```
Ext.define('app.view.panel.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myPanel',
    height: 360,
    width: 480,
    layout:'fit',
    title: 'My Panel',
    initComponent: function(){
        var me =this;
        me.items=[{
            xtype:'button',
            itemId: 'myButton'
            ... 
        }]
        this.callParent(arguments);

    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can search and access components by using the
`Ext.Component.query` and passing along the itemId, refer to following links:-

http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/chapter2/lesson5/2.cfm
http://devjs.eu/en/how-to-use-ext-component-query-in-ext-js-4/